# Docker Communication between 2 apps inside same container

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have two apps -- app1 is running on localhost/app1. app2 which exposes api is running on localhost/app2 .Both these apps uses nginx server. App1 is makes an HTTP GET request to app2, which throws cURL error 7: Failed to connect.

But when containerizing both of these apps (and running them on the same network), what url should app1 be sending to fetch the api details?

Docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - "83:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - php
    volumes:
      - /code:/var/www/html

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - /code:/var/www/html
```

Code Directory has 2 folders app1 and app2, Where app1 is the application code base and app2 is the api code base

Virutalhost entry mounted inside web container

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name default;
  root        /var/www/html;
  index       index.html index.php;
 client_max_body_size 100M;
  fastcgi_read_timeout 1800;
  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
  }
  location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    expires       max;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log    off;  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files     $uri =404;
    include       fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_pass  lamp_php_1:9000;
  }
}
```

Comment: please provide your Dockerfile/docker-compose , so we can help you

Comment: @LinSel, Edited the Question with Docker-compose file and folder structure.